# How to change a list so that .setValues will display it in a specific range on a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm basically a beginner with coding and Google Apps Script and have hit the limits of my abilities. I have a list of values in Column A on sheet 1, and a second list (subset) in Column A on sheet 2. Sheet 1 is updated manually and includes a record number, file name, and color. Sheet 2 is only files designated "blue" in the color column and the goal is to run a check that makes sure that all record numbers for blue files from sheet 1 are on sheet 2, and if not, to add them.

Edited to add:
samplefile: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ji3R24V5y7j--1icUc4DpzOtulnEK9qT5N92lhuYSLI/edit?usp=viewing

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName('MasterList');  
    var blueSheet = ss.getSheetByName('blue');

    var records = masterSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

    var lastBlue = blueSheet.getLastRow();
    var blueListAssigned = blueSheet.getRange(2,1,lastBlue-1, 1).getValues().flat();


    function getBluesOnly() {
      var allBlue = [];
      var newBlue = [];
      var colorColumn = records[0].indexOf("color");
      var recordColumn = records[0].indexOf("record");

      Logger.log('all records: ' +records);
      Logger.log('Blue finished ' +blueListAssigned);


     //Only keep records from MasterList when color is blue
   
      records.filter (function (row) {
        return (row[colorColumn] === "blue");
        })
       
      .forEach(function (row) {
      var newBlueRecord = row[recordColumn];
      allBlue.push(newBlueRecord);
   
        });
    
      Logger.log('All Blue Records: '+allBlue);

      //Check to see if blue records from MasterList are already on the Blue Sheet (assigned to blue)
  
      allBlue.forEach(function(each){
       if(!blueListAssigned.includes(each))
       {newBlue.push(each)}
       
        });
  
      Logger.log('New Blues to add: ' +newBlue);


      var firstBlankRow = blueSheet.getRange(lastBlue+1, 1, newBlue.length,1);
      var postNewBlues = blueSheet.setActiveRange(firstBlankRow);

      postNewBlues.setValues(newBlue);


    };
```

When I run this, all the logs show that all lists have the correct records in them, but then at the end I get this error:

Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.

How do I change the parameters of newBlue so that those items can be added to the spreadsheet?

(I'm also open to completely different strategies for accomplishing this goal if there's a better approach)

Comment: What is a blue file?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which is reproducible by us. (i.e. that includes a sample of your data.)

Comment: here's the sample file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ji3R24V5y7j--1icUc4DpzOtulnEK9qT5N92lhuYSLI/edit?usp=sharing:

Comment: Everything you need for the code should be posted in the question. I do not follow links to other google accounts

Comment: apologies, as I said I'm new.  Sheet 1 includes 3 columns; record, name, and color. I'm trying to filter for those rows where the color is blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the blue lines:

```
function filterthebluelines() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("MasterList");
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const idx = hs.reduce((a, h, i) => (a[h] = i, a), {})
  const blue = vs.filter((r,i) => r[idx["color"]] == "blue").map(r => r)
  blue.unshift(['record','name','color']);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(blue).replace(/],/g,'],\n'));//Added the replacement so lines would display vertically.  Otherwise blue is a a 2d array suitable for use in setValues() method.
}

Execution log
1:54:06 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:54:07 PM  Info    [["record","name","color"],
["A2","B2","blue"],
["A5","B5","blue"],
["A8","B8","blue"],
["A11","B11","blue"]]
1:54:08 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Data:

| record | name | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | B2 | blue |
| A3 | B3 | red |
| A4 | B4 | green |
| A5 | B5 | blue |
| A6 | B6 | red |
| A7 | B7 | green |
| A8 | B8 | blue |
| A9 | B9 | red |
| A10 | B10 | green |
| A11 | B11 | blue |

Comment: I can make that work! Thank you for your patience, and your help